# How can I add the labels on the bar charts?

Tags: r, count, percentage

I have run the code like this but dont know how to add the labels inside the charts, pls help me

```
ggplot(Retention.df, aes(x=Housing_Resident, y = ..count.., fill=Fall_Not_Retained))+
geom_bar(position="fill", colour="black")+
  ylab("Proportion")+xlab('Housing_Resident')+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
          legend.title=element_text(size=16), 
          legend.text=element_text(size=16),
          strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq9Dk.png)

Comment: please don't use incorrect tags, this has nothing to do with [tag:python]/[tag:pandas]

Answer (score 0):

you need the add the `label = ...` argument in your aes() and then use `geom_label()`

Comment: I mean make labels with ratios instead of counts